# Unity ToBuiltIn() Error ? Easy Answer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

***Everything I am writing this all with the Unity API***

So I have this code to help me generate terrain:

```
Array CreateTerrainVertices(float[] _heightmap, float _resolution)
{
    Debug.Log("Creating terrain vertices");
    // The minimum resolution is 1
    resolution = Mathf.Max(1, resolution);

    Array vertices = new Array();

    // For each point, in the heightmap, create a vertex for
    // the top and the bottom of the terrain.
    for (int i = 0; i < _heightmap.Length; i++) {

        vertices.Push(new Vector2(i / resolution, _heightmap[i]));
        vertices.Push(new Vector2(i / resolution, 0));
    }

    Debug.Log("Created " + vertices.length + " terrain vertices");
    return vertices.ToBuiltin(Vector2) as Vector2[];
}
```

Everything works beyond perfect in this script! except that every last line!

```
return vertices.ToBuiltin(Vector2) as Vector2[];
```

I receive the error "Vector2 is a type, which is not valid in this context". But when I remove the the Vector2 making it look like:

```
return vertices.ToBuiltin() as Vector2[];
```

it tells me I need a type in the parameters... But looking at the first error I got it says "Vector2 is a type...".

How can I fix this? What belongs there?

Comment: Is this JavaScript or C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a flexible sized Array object, adding a fixed number of elements and trying to convert it to a fixed size array afterwards.

The right way to use UnityEngine.Lang.Array.ToBuiltIn(Type) is by passing it a Type object, specifying the type the objects should be converted to.

```
return vertices.ToBuiltIn(typeof(Vector2)); // I am removing the "as Vector2[]" as it has no effect
```

This however is an inefficient solution overall, because the array will have to be resized several times during its composition and afterwards, converted. Why not create the array with the correct type and size right away?

```
Array CreateTerrainVertices(float[] _heightmap, float _resolution)
{
    Debug.Log("Creating terrain vertices");
    // The minimum resolution is 1
    resolution = Mathf.Max(1, resolution);

    Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[_heightmap.Length * 2];

    // For each point, in the heightmap, create a vertex for
    // the top and the bottom of the terrain.
    for (int i = 0; i < _heightmap.Length; i++)
    {
        vertices[i * 2] = new Vector2(i / resolution, _heightmap[i]);
        vertices[i * 2 + 1] = new Vector2(i / resolution, 0);
    }

    Debug.Log("Created " + vertices.length + " terrain vertices");
    return vertices;
}
```